# How to make our WebSphere Portal server to work with https?

Tags: websphere

I want to make my url to support http and https as well,Can you please tell me what is the configuration needs to be done.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM has a guide on this: [Setting up SSL](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Setting_up_SSL_wp7)